# AttributeError: 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'profile'

Tags: django, django-forms

I have built a Django app and it worked well.
When I had run an another django app in a port(localhost:8000) and tried the app I built on the port, it says error like this.

```
AttributeError: 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'profile'
```

Here is my code:

```
class DashboardView(auth_views.LoginView):
    template_name = "dashboard/home.html"
    verify_email_required = 'registration/verify_email_required.html'
    form_class = ProfiledAuthenticationForm
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # context = {'form': self.form_class()}
        
        context = self.get_context_data()
        context['form'] = self.form_class()
        
        if request.user.profile.is_verified:        
            return render(request, self.template_name, context)
        else:           
            
            return render(request, self.verify_email_required, context)
```

Note: Initial when I built the app, it worked well, but for now it takes error. when user does not log in, the homepage was redirected to login page.

Comment: You have this error because the code `request.user.profile.is_verified` is correct only if the user is **authenticated**. Try to add an authenticated close before.

Comment: Yeah, I know but I know the class(DashboardView) is called if user is authenticated. I am right or not? I am not sure about the auth_views.LoginView

Comment: No use instead `from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin` and `class DashboardView(LoginRequiredMixin)`.

Comment: when I replace that, it took an error; AttributeError: type object 'DashboardView' has no attribute 'as_view'

Answer (score 0):

When I fixed like this, it runs well.

```
class DashboardView(auth_views.LoginView):
    template_name = "dashboard/home.html"
    verify_email_required = 'registration/verify_email_required.html'
    form_class = ProfiledAuthenticationForm
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # context = {'form': self.form_class()}
        
        context = self.get_context_data()
        context['form'] = self.form_class()
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            if request.user.profile.is_verified:        
                return render(request, self.template_name, context)
            return render(request, self.verify_email_required, context)
        return render(request, self.template_name, context)
```